# Minecraft Forge 1.8 - Loading Block Textures

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I have just started learning Java while modding Minecraft. I have watched a tutorial on adding the blocks into the game using the Minecraft Forge API, but I have a problem. There is no longer the ".setBlockTextureName ()" method, so I don't know what to do. I have a simple block added into my game, but it has no texture and I want to add a texture to it. How would I do this for Minecraft 1.8?

P.S.: If this is a duplicate, I am sorry, I only saw questions about Minecraft mobs, not textures for 1.8 (keep that in mind, the Forge API for 1.8 is different than every other version), so I decided to ask myself.

If I need to clarify anything, please, let me know!

Comment: Can I suggest using 1.7 instead? 1.8 seems to have a lot of problems at the moment, and most people playing modded Minecraft are playing 1.7 anyway.

Comment: Version 1.8 is relatively new, I would also suggest using 1.7 version until a more stable version of forge comes out.

Comment: Well, I suppose I could. I mean, 1.8 does really, mainly, add blocks. I guess I will go to 1.7 again, but knowing how to mod 1.8 would be nice.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Texturing is very different in 1.8. Here are some tutorials:

[Updating Blocks](http://www.wuppy29.com/minecraft/1-8-tutorial/updating-1-7-to-1-8-part-3-basic-blocks/#sthash.gLIhasJ3.mBBGMx04.dpbs);
[Updating Items](http://www.wuppy29.com/minecraft/1-8-tutorial/updating-1-7-to-1-8-part-2-basic-items/#sthash.scik3Pfo.Ae1Q2wl7.dpbs).

For both of the above:

- Remove any `GameRegistry.registerBlock` from the main mod class. These should now be in the block/item's constructor.
- Add a `private final` `name` field and create a getter for it.

For **blocks**:

- In `src/main/resources/assets/{MODID}/models/block` you will need 2 JSON files.
  The first should be called `{BLOCKNAME}.json` and contain this:

  ```
  {
      "parent": "block/cube_all",
      "textures": {
          "all": "{MODID}:blocks/{BLOCKNAME}"
      }
  }
  ```

  The second has the same name, goes in `src/main/resources/assets/{MODID}/models/item`, and has this code:

  ```
  {
      "parent": "{MODID}:block/{BLOCKNAME}",
      "display": {
          "thirdperson": {
              "rotation": [ 10, -45, 170 ],
              "translation": [ 0, 1.5, -2.75 ],
              "scale": [ 0.375, 0.375, 0.375 ]
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Now in `src/main/resources/assets/{MODID}/blockstates`, you need 1 more JSON file. With the same name, it should hold this code:

  ```
  {
      "variants": {
          "normal": { "model": "{MODID}:{BLOCKNAME}" }
      }
  }
  ```

You should replace `{MODID}` and `{BLOCKNAME}` with your mod's ID and block's name, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading [Minecraft Modding](http://greyminecraftcoder.blogspot.com.au/2014/12/block-models-18.html)

> The way that Minecraft renders blocks has changed significantly for 1.8.  Previously, the shape of blocks was defined in the java code.  This meant that (for example) a BlockTorch would always have the same shape, and only the textures could be changed.  Minecraft now uses model files to define both the shape and the texture.

in particular "Some Clarifications of some of the key points" on the above page.

See also: [Block models](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Model#Block_models)

Comment: I have moved to making a game with a team now. :) Thanks though, I have been thinking of making a Minecraft mod for fun for a while now lol.